# Org macros misbehave in include file

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

I am using [org-reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal) for presentation

It has a `#+BEGIN_NOTES` for [creating speaker notes](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal#speaker-notes)

Tried to shorten with this macro `n` following this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759592/3700414)

```
 #+MACRO: n (eval "\n#+BEGIN_NOTES\n$1\n#+END_NOTES\n")
```

It works if I use `{{{n(some notes)}}}` in a single file

But if the file `#+Include:` some other file I get strange errors on export:

```
eval: Wrong number of arguments: eval, 5
```

This is org mode version 8.3beta

When I switched to 9.3.8 I got an eval error in the outside file itself

And org 9.4 doesnt load at all so I assumed its too bleeding edge and hurriedly went back

Yeah my emacs is a bit old: 24.5.1; can't afford an upgrade at this point

---

## Added later in response to @NickD

I tried digging...
And found that

`org-export-expand-as` doesn't seem to be used in org-reveal.

So I did the following

- Moved the macro out from the org into lisp and removed the `eval`

```
(setq org-export-global-macros '(("n" . "\n#+BEGIN_NOTES\n$1\n#+END_NOTES\n")))
```

- Ran

```
M-:  (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
M-:  (org-macro-replace-all org-export-global-macros)
```

After this reveal exporter works

Unfortunately my simplistic try at automating the above doesnt work

```lisp
(defun mymacro-expand ()
  (widen)
  (let ((c (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
    (with-temp-file "ttt.org"
      (insert c)
      (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
      (org-macro-replace-all org-export-global-macros))
))
```

3. I guess I should file a org-reveal bug report

But if you can suggest an alternative to above using org-expand-as that'd be great!

---

## Addition 2

Downloaded and compiled emacs

Now its at version 28.0.50
Org version 9.4

It now seems that the `$1` inside the string breaks whereas the `format` version doesn't.

Error message is `eval: Wrong number of arguments: eval, 4`

Can you try with these two files?

```
$ cat foo.org 
#+TITLE: Some title
#+MACRO: n (eval "\n#+BEGIN_NOTES\n$1\n#+END_NOTES\n")
* Outside heading
#+Include: bar.org

$ cat bar.org
* Inside heading
Some text
{{{n(internal note)}}}
Some more text
```

Comment: It should be `org-export-as`. But is this still 8.3? That's too old to have it. Moveing to the latest version of org that works with your emacs is recommended, I think.

Comment: @NickD I don't see any org-export-as either : https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/master/ox-reveal.el And yes, my digging around was all in 9.3.8

Comment: `org-export-as` is the Org mode function that gets called at the top level to export a file: it orchestrates the export by calling functions defined in each exporter (in a table-driven fashon) so you will find it as I pointed out indirectly in my comment (after my answer) in `ox.el`, *not* in any particular exporter.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html): Within such templates, arguments become strings. So `"\n#+BEGIN_NOTES\n$1\n#+END_NOTES\n"` becomes `"\n#+BEGIN_NOTES\n"internal note"\n#+END_NOTES\n"`. That is why only the format version works.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work on fairly recent Org mode and Emacs: Org mode version 9.4 (release_9.4-3-ge6021b @ /home/nick/elisp/org-mode/lisp/) -
GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.32, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-06-15).

- foo.org:

```
#+MACRO: n (eval (format "\n#+BEGIN_NOTES\n%s\n#+END_NOTES\n" $1))

* Link

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/org-macros-misbehave-in-include-file

* foo

#+include: bar.org

{{{n(foo)}}}
```

- bar.org:

```
{{{n(bar)}}}
```

Result of exporting `foo.org`to LaTeX is:

```
% Created 2020-10-14 Wed 09:30
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\author{Nick Dokos}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Nick Dokos},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 28.0.50 (Org mode 9.4)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{Link}
\label{sec:org59c7ca7}

\url{https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/org-macros-misbehave-in-include-file}

\section{foo}
\label{sec:org8b3fe52}


\begin{NOTES}
bar
\end{NOTES}



\begin{NOTES}
foo
\end{NOTES}
\end{document}
```

Result of exporting it to HTML using the `ox-reveal` library from MELPA (only the `<body>...</body>` part of the file is shown to save some space):

```
<body>
<div class="reveal">
<div class="slides">
<section id="sec-title-slide"><h2 class="author">Nick Dokos</h2><p class="date">Created: 2020-10-14 Wed 13:08</p>
</section>
<section id="table-of-contents"><div id="table-of-contents">
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
<ul>
<li><a href="#/slide-org4e9fdef">1. Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#/slide-org464c226">2. foo</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section>
<section id="slide-org4e9fdef">
<h2 id="org4e9fdef"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> Link</h2>
<p>
<a href="https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/org-macros-misbehave-in-include-file">https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61189/org-macros-misbehave-in-include-file</a>
</p>

</section>
</section>
<section>
<section id="slide-org464c226">
<h2 id="org464c226"><span class="section-number-2">2</span> foo</h2>
<aside class="notes">
<p>
bar
</p>

</aside>



<aside class="notes">
<p>
foo
</p>

</aside>
</section>
</section>
</div>
</div>
<script src="./reveal.js/js/reveal.js"></script>

<script>
// Full list of configuration options available here:
// https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
Reveal.initialize({
multiplex: {
    secret: '', // null if client
    id: '', // id, obtained from socket.io server
    url: '' // Location of socket.io server
},

// Optional libraries used to extend on reveal.js
dependencies: [
 { src: './reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
 { src: './reveal.js/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
 { src: './reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
 { src: './reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } },
 { src: './reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } }]
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems a bug in org-reveal : include processing not proper

Comment: The include processing is done by `org-export-as`, so it is generic (and so it the macro processing BTW : they are [steps 1 and 3-4](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/ox.el#L2948) in `org-export-as` so they are done before any specific exporter gets its hands on the text), so `org-reveal` would have to go to some lengths to screw it up. It would be worth digging down a bit I think.

Comment: Installed `ox-reveal` and exported the above file with it: no problems.

Comment: When I changed the macro to use format as you've done I get `Symbol's function definition is void: seq-filter` So I guess it comes down to an emacs version issue (I see seq-filter and seq-map in ox-reveal.el and undefined in my emacs) Do you by any chance know if they are in cl-lib and simple enough to copy out?

Comment: New addition 2. Can you please check? (both reveal and latex exporters)

Comment: I checked that earlier: you need `format`. The macro processor breaks "foo $1 bar" into three strings. It does not matter outside of `eval`, but with `eval` it does not work.